# How to update a variable from a text file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, let's say that I got a shell script that generates a v.py on the output that contains

```
v = some-float
```

And I'm accessing it in the main.py script via `from v import v`
But later the main Script toggles generation process again and the variable in v.py gets updated, but the variable `v` is not updating for the main script.

To make main script work I need to update the variable from v.py while script is running

I've tried `importlib.reload(v)` - didn't work

I'm still new to python and don't understand it completely

Comment: You might want to lookup on how to read from and write to text file in Python

Comment: You could rely on `v.v` instead of `v`. In this case, `importlib.reload` allows for the value of `v.v` to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are using python 3.*, v needs to be a module, so the way you import it changes to example below.

```
import v
import importlib

print(v.v)

with open('v.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('v = 20.0')

importlib.reload(v)
print(v.v)
```

Also note the document of [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

"When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem."

Though our minimal example works, this is something to bear in mind for more complicated cases.